# Is this DB design acceptable, or is there a better way?

Tags: mysql, normalization

Is this normalized properly ?? is there a more efficient way to design this DB ?

A Profile can have unlimited albums, any user can create an album from anyone's videos.
An album may contain many videos, and a video can belong to multiple albums. 
This is the way I've done it. . .

```
[Table] Profile
   [pk] Id
        (first, Last, Email. . . ect)

[Table] Album
   [pk] Id
        Title
   [fk] Owner (Profile.Id)
        Created


[Table] AlbumContent
   [pk] Id
   [fk] Album (Album.Id)
   [fk] Video (Video.Id)

[Table] Video
   [pk] Id
   [fk] Owner (Profile.Id)
```

Is there a better / more efficient way. . . (should I 'merge' Album and AlbumContent into one table... or is that a no-no ?? )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[Table] Album
   [pk] Id
        Title
   [fk] Owner (Profile.Id)
        Created


[Table] AlbumContent
   [fk][pk] Album (Album.Id)
   [fk][pk] Video (Video.Id)
```

i would use composite primary key on Album content
Album content doesnt realy need surrogate pk
unless youe want one video multiple times in your album

Answer (score 1):

I would just rename AlbumContent to AlbumVideos if all the content is videos.

Also, if an Album can have more than 1 video then I would NOT 'merge' Album and AlbumContent into one table.

Otherwise I think the design is ok.